# Why does respondsToSelector not work for me in this case?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a little conundrum that is driving me right up the wall.  I am using delegation pretty heavily as a pattern in an application I am writing.  I'm trying to be as "careful" in the code calling the delegate as I can by testing the delegate with "[delegate respondsToSelector]" on each delegated call.  Everything works fine unless I am in a UIView subclass.  In that case, respondsToSelector returns NO yet I can safely call the delegate code so clearly it exists and works correctly.

I have boiled it down to the most simple example I can below.  Any help you can provide would be appreciated:

Inside of my UIView subclass's .h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol TestDelegate <NSObject>
@optional
-(double)GetLineWidth;
@end

@interface ViewSubclass : UIView {
    id<TestDelegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) id<TestDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

Inside my delegate class's .h file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "ViewSubclass.h"

@interface ViewDelegate : NSObject <TestDelegate> {

}

@end
```

Inside my delegate class's .m file:

```
#import "ViewDelegate.h"

@implementation ViewDelegate

-(double)GetLineWidth {
    return 25.0;
}

@end
```

Inside my UIView subclass's .m file:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    double lineWidth = 2.0;

    if (delegate == nil) {
        ViewDelegate *vd = [[ViewDelegate alloc]init];
        delegate = vd;
    }

    // If I comment out the "if" statement and just call the delegate
    // delegate directly, the call works!
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(GetLineWidth:)]) {
        lineWidth = [delegate GetLineWidth];
    }

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, lineWidth);
```

Comment: Typically you would not want to retain delegates `@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TestDelegate> delegate;`

Comment: What Rob Said; that method should be called `lineWidth`.  Methods should never start with uppercase letters and should only start with `get` in very rare circumstances.  This is not a style choice, this is a pattern that you must follow for all of the features of the framework to work correctly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

the selector for `-(double)GetLineWidth` is `@selector(GetLineWidth)`.

you have an extra colon in your selector.

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(GetLineWidth:)]) {
                                                       ^
```

Comment: And rename `GetLineWidth` to `lineWidth`. Do not preference accessors with "Get" and do no to start with a leading cap. It matters in Cocoa, it is not just a style choice.

Comment: Note that @user704315 **would have been right** if `GetLineWidth` took one argument i.e. the selector for `-(double)GetLineWidthForSomething:something` is `@selector(GetLineWidthForSomething:)`

Answer (score 3):

Replace *if-statement* with this one:

```
if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(GetLineWidth)]) {
    lineWidth = [delegate GetLineWidth];
}
```