# Using a NSSavePanel from Qt for a native save dialog

Tags: macos, qt5, objective-c++

The code below works most of the time, maybe a more experienced Objective C++ programmer can help me:

Issue 1: When called from specific menu QActions, the system starts to animate the dialog into existence and then automatically closes it before it is drawn full size; the return code is -1000. For other specific actions it always works correctly.

Issue 2: I try to disable the Tags field but it still shows on Mavericks. If I remove the if statement the tags field is hidden on Mavericks but the program crashes on Lion.

```
// Use native dialog to save a file
QString GetCocoaSaveFile(const QString &prompt, const QString &source_dir, const QString &filename)
{
  QString selected_file;

  NSSavePanel *panel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
  [panel setFloatingPanel:YES];

  if([panel respondsToSelector:@selector(setShowsTagField)])  // Only available on 10.9+
    [panel setShowsTagField:NO];

  NSString *title_ns = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:prompt.toUtf8().data()];
  [panel setTitle:title_ns];

  NSString *path_ns = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:source_dir.toUtf8().data()];
  NSURL *directory_url = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:path_ns];
  [panel setDirectoryURL:directory_url];

  NSString *default_ns = nil;
  if(!filename.isEmpty())
  {
    default_ns = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:filename.toUtf8().data()];
    [panel setNameFieldStringValue:default_ns];
  }

  NSInteger result = [panel runModal];

  if(result == NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
  {
    NSURL *result_url = [panel URL];
    NSString *path_sel = [result_url path];
    selected_file = QString::fromUtf8([path_sel UTF8String]);
  }

  if(default_ns) [default_ns release];
  [directory_url release];
  [path_ns release];
  [title_ns release];

  return(selected_file);
}
```

I'm using Qt 5.2.0 if that is relevant.

Comment: Why don't you use the static function QFileDialog.getSaveFileName() which according to Qt docs will use the native dialog?

Comment: @bootchk In Qt 5.2.0 on Mac, `getSaveFileName()` doesn't open in the directory specified by its parameter; also I want to disable the tags part of the dialog because there is no way to access this information using Qt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also observed the issue #1 (Qt 4.8.0).
It can be fixed by using QApplication::processEvents () before showing the dialog.

```
QApplication::processEvents ();
NSInteger result = [panel runModal];
```

Comment: See my answer for how to hide the tags field.

Comment: This just saved me a bit of frustration -- had no idea why OS X native dialogs were closing immediately!

Answer (score 0):

Your looking for something like this:

```
NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel]; // get an autorelease open panel
[panel setPrompt:NSLocalizedString(@"Open", @"Open")];
[panel setShowsTagField:OFF];                 // Turns off the tags
qApp->processEvent();                         // Gets Qt to play nice with the next line
NSInteger result = [panel runModal];
```

Works perfectly with Qt 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the tags field is shown under Mavericks is that the following line is wrong:

```
if([panel respondsToSelector:@selector(setShowsTagField)])
```

The `setShowsTagField` takes an argument so the correct selector must have a colon after it:

```
if([panel respondsToSelector:@selector(setShowsTagField:)])
                                                       ^
```

and then everything works.

[This question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257078/why-does-respondstoselector-not-work-for-me-in-this-case) made me realise that this was the problem.